# What is wrong with my php/cakephp syntax?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, syntax

Although I'm doing this in cakephp, i believe I have a terrible php-syntax-newbie-mistake in my code, but I can't decipher the correct way.

The mistake is in the line:

```
'logo' => $validateArray
```

Apparently I have no clue on how to write that line, without repeating the above text.

```
var $validateArray = array(
    'rule1' => array(
        'rule' => 'isCompletedUpload',
        'message' => 'File was not uploaded '  
    ),
    'written' => array( 
        'rule' => 'isSuccessfulWrite', 
        'message' => 'blah'
     )
);
public $validate = array(
    'logo' => $validateArray
);
```

Comment: Hello aziz.punjani, I'm using 5.3.8

Comment: you probably want the `$validate` array populated inside of the `__construct` to be `$this->validate = array('logo' => $this->validateArray);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization of class property must be a **constant value**, can't contain a variable.

You need to initialize it in the constructor instead.

```
public $validate;

public function __construct() {
  $this->validate = array(
    'logo' => $this->validateArray;
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is great to know. If the array "$validateArray" never changes. Is there a way to declare it constant?

Comment: Because when I try to use the construct like this, cakePHP gives me thi error "Error: Table for model was not found in datasource default."

Comment: @FloresRobles Try read cakePHP's document and follow the example. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with cakePHP.

Comment: Thanks, finally i got it working. Using your way, just added              parent::__construct($options); which was tricky for me.